# Why does adding spans change letter position or width in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I've ran into an interesting issue, that I believe might be related to Chrome, or even the font I've been using.

In certain parts of this app, spans are wrapped around each letter, after a bit of time. Once this happens, there's a slight shift of letter position. I'm not sure if this is the width, margin, or something else. But, it's most noticeable around the letter "W" and "A".

In the example, you'll see the issue after 1 second, when the letters are wrapped in a span.

[Link to JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ky8Ldpa/7/).

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var wrapFinal = $(".wrap");
  wrapFinal.html(wrapFinal.text().replace(/./g, "<span>$&</span>"));
}, 1000);
```

```css
.wrap {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">aWsdasWdWds</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's related to kerning. I mean something happens to kerning of your font when inline wrappers are used

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure - I've tried adding letter-spacing to the spans just to see if that helped, but didn't do much. The other thing is I noticed it's a lot worse in other fonts as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely a kerning issue.

Since you wrap single characters into `span` elements, the font engine will no more consider the text as a continuous string; and how could it - the spans could be formatted to appear anywhere, or disappear altogether for that matter.

More formally put, the `span` elements will get each their own box models for rendering. The contents of the boxes will be rendered independently, so there is no possibility for the text renderer to use kerning strategies.

If you want the representations with and without `span`s to appear similar to each other, you could try to gently hint the kerning engine to stop what it's doing by setting [`font-kerning: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning).

Comment: Awesome - thanks. New fiddle works perfectly as intended. https://jsfiddle.net/7ky8Ldpa/8/